# LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:License Limit Exceeded Salesforce

Tags: apex, user, userlicense

Hi I am working with sales force and from my code i am trying to create a salesforce user and the attributes which i am passing is mention below:

```
{
"User" : "freeuser",
"Alias" : "freeuser",
"Email" : "freeuser.freeuser@freeuser.com",
"EmailEncodingKey" : "ISO-8859-1",
"LanguageLocaleKey" : "en_US",
"LastName" : "freeuser",
"LocaleSidKey" : "en_US",
"TimeZoneSidKey" : "America/Los_Angeles",
"Username" : "freeuser.freeuser@freeuser.com",
"UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin":"false",
"UserPermissionsMarketingUser":"false",
"UserPermissionsOfflineUser":"false",
"ProfileId" : "00e280000016hS2AAI"
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
[SaveResult  errors='{[2][Error  fields='{[0]}'
 message='License Limit Exceeded'
 statusCode='LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED'
]
,[Error  fields='{[0]}'
message='license limit exceeded'
statusCode='LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED'
]
,}'
id='null'
success='false'
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Error itself stating that you are exceeding license limit. In that case you need to purchase new license or you need to deactivate a user for that particular license.

You can check remaining license count under

**Setup-> Company Information -> User Licenses related list.**

[image]

Comment: hi but i am not creating user license i am creating user, and i tried deactivating existing users also , it is throwing the same error

Comment: While creating any user salesforce need a license. Without assigning a license you can't create a new user.

Comment: so what shall i do , i want to create user , shall i delete some license , please suggest something to make it work

Comment: What type of user you are trying to create?Deactivate a user in your org manually of that type which will free a license for you. After that run your code

Comment: @Utsav ..dont use cloned profile (User License:High Volume Customer Portal).use standard profile (High Volume Customer Portal User). i got same issue. i changed profile now working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy more Salesforce licenses, currently you are at the maximum and Salesforce does not permit you to create another user. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: hi but i am not creating user license i am creating user, and i tried deactivating existing users also , it is throwing the same error